# NodeJitsu error: Error: ENOENT, stat '/opt/run/snapshot/

Tags: node.js, express, nodejitsu

My app’s folder structure for NodeJitsu is as follows (i.e., when i do a `jitsu deploy`, I'm in the folder that contains "server.js" - i.e., the "server" folder).

```
Root    server
        |___server.js
        |___package.json
        client
        |___www
            |___index.html
                |___css
                |___js
                |___etc.
```

So at the root is the folder "server", containing the starting script, “server.js”. Then there’s a folder called “client”, parallel to "server", with a folder within that called “www”, and within “www” is the main “index.html”.

In my “server.js” file, I have the following code:

```
app.get(‘/’, function(req,res)
{
    var aPath = path.resolve(“../client/www/”, “index.html”);
    res.sendFile(aPath);
});
```

I don’t have a `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/somefolder')`. And when I start the app, I get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT, stat '/opt/run/snapshot/client/www/index.html'
```

My `process.cwd()` is `/opt/run/snapshot/package`. Obviously the above path isn’t pointing to the location where “index.html” resides. But I thought the way I do the `path.resolve(…)` should point to “index.html”. I can’t see where the problem is. If “server.js” is in the root, then to get to “index.html”, which is in “client/www/index.html”, then I should need to write “../client/www”, relative to the excuting script, to get to “index.html”, right?.

Do you have any insights as to where the path is not set up correctly? What should `/opt/run/snapshot/` be pointing to? Or, what changes do I need to make in the `get(‘/’)` handler to correctly point to my “index.html”?

***EDIT***

I incorrectly drew the folder structure. Now it's correct.

I also turned off the `app.get()` and turned on the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client/www/')`. But to no avail: now i get a `Cannot GET /` error.

What I'm ultimately after is to have the "server.js" file be the Node server that, mostly, just serves AngularJS HTML files to the browser, with attendant images, stylesheets, etc., from the "client" folder. This is the server's main role, with an additional role of authenticating the app's users, employing the very nice Satellizer module. And that's it. I have a MongoDB attached, but otherwise this is a very common and straightforward Node.js server app.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it working locally? Your CLIENT and WWW are in caps, make sure it's not a case issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without rooting, resolving and log out to double check:

```
// notice no leading / which is root.  __dirname should be the dir of current file running
var staticPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/www');
console.log(staticPath);
```

Then pass that into express.static

```
app.use(express.static(staticPath);
```

I would probably recommend following the layout and convention of express generated apps with app in the root and static files under public

```
/public
   <static files>
app.js
```

Then do what the generated app does:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: OK, thanks, bryanmac; i will try your suggestions. Appreciate it!

Comment: After those changes, the __dirname is "/opt/run/snapshot/package", and with the staticPath as you create it, the new path becomes staticPath='/opt/run/snapshot/client/www' but I thought it should be staticPath='/opt/run/snapshot/package/client/www'. 

But - IT WORKS! So, thanks very much again. Appreciate your time.